# Why doesn't Adobe Edge animation work after copying generated code into an html file in a different directory?

Tags: javascript, animation, directory, adobe-edge

I'm trying to keep all the files Edge generates separate from my main files.

This is the html in the file it publishes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="anim_edgePreload.js"></script>
<style>
    .edgeLoad-EDGE-20819118 { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-20819118">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I copied the code over to an html file outside the animation folder containing all the generated files and changed the directory of the JS file it's referring to.

anim_edgePreload.js --> edgeAnimation/anim_edgePreload.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Untitled</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="edgeAnimation/anim_edgePreload.js"></script>
<style>
    .edgeLoad-EDGE-20819118 { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-20819118">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The animation no longer appears on the page, any idea why?

I get this error in Firebug after a few seconds:

TypeError: AdobeEdge.okToLaunchComposition is not a function

function edgeCallback(a){htFallbacks[a]&&(a=htFallbacks[a]);AdobeEdge.preload.got[a]=!0;if(a==AdobeEdge.preload.last)AdobeEdge.okToLaunchComposition(compId),AdobeEdge.preload.busy=!1,AdobeEdge.preload.q.length>0&&(a=AdobeEdge.preload.q.pop(),AdobeEdge.requestResources(a.files,a.callback))}

Comment: Instead of voting my question down, how about telling me why my question isn't good? At least then I could change the way I think about my approach.

Comment: For this kind of issue, please view the video here.
This video will demonstrate what you need to do, in order to have your files
Located in SubFolders. http://youtu.be/RQKqlpCkrjs And this s a valid question. good luck
Wayne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My issue was displaying the animation in a **div** on another page. Any attempt to load the animation explicitly failed. I succeeded in resolving this issue by using the HTML **object** tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Banner</title>

</head>

<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">

<object data="animations/liferay/liferay-00.html" style="height:175px; width:100%"></object>

</body>
</html>
```

Do note I did NOT change any of my URL paths. All I did was point to the publish folder.

So if you still encounter issues try re-publishing.

**Update:**
Additional solution provided by **Wayne Barron**:
http://youtu.be/RQKqlpCkrjs

Comment: Welcome! Glad it helped. Feel free to ask me anything about CSS3 or Edge Animate anytime.

Comment: Excellent solution, I spent one day trying to figure out how to integrate it in my MVC project.  I also agree with you about down vote, it was not called for.  Thanks again for posting this answer.